# Accessing and Modifying 'Viva Insights' data via script (GraphApi or Powershell)

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I can use "Viva Insights" to modify my Office Hours (Lunch Hours) via https://insights.viva.office.com/#/PersonalApp/AppSettings/WorkWeekSettings/
[image]

How do I modify the same via GraphApi or PowerShell or some automated means?

I am an Exchange Admin. We have a hybrid environment with all users in O365 (Cloud).
We have to modify the properties for over 2000 users and I am looking at an automated way.

I am seeing that the 'Viva Insights' data is stored in the mailbox as in https://sharegate.com/blog/what-is-microsoft-viva-insights. But I cannot find where in the O365 mailbox it is located. I tried doing a Get-Mailbox and Get-MailboxStatistics.
I also tried Ms Graph (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and I see something for Viva Goals but unfortunately nothing for Viva Insights.

I tried doing a 'Get-VivaInsightsSettings -Identity E937@zzzz.com | fl' but I do not see any thing for office hours/lunch hours.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/connect-to-microsoft-365-powershell?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: See calendar method here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/?view=exchange-ps#mailboxes

Comment: Thanks @jdweng . Yes, I tried doing a 'Get-VivaInsightsSettings -Identity E937@zzzz.com | fl' but I do not see any thing for office hours/lunch hours. Is there a something specific that you see that can export / modify this specific data?

Comment: Get-CalendarProcessing and Get-MailboxCalendarFolder

Comment: Tried running Get-CalendarProcessing E937  | fl and Get-MailboxCalendarFolder -Identity E937@zzzz.com:\Calendar | fl. Unfortunately they return no data specific to office hours/lunch hours. Also tried the equivalent Get Commands and there is no reference to modifying office hours/lunch hours.

Comment: Your identity is wrong format.  You use the username not email address.  See : https://unifiedpeople.ru/exch2013onpremhelp.en/html/dba2cebb-3c37-40ce-8ac0-93ec8d79ce0d.htm

Comment: I was able to modify the Office hours with Set-MailboxCalendarConfiguration -Identity e1327 -WorkingHoursStartTime "07:00:00" -WorkingHoursEndTime "15:00:00" (and it shows in Viva Insights as well) .... But I need a way to modify "Lunch hours"

Comment: Can you see the lunch hours setting using the GET method?

Comment: Is lunch an appointment?  Following code says lunch was an appointment : https://unlockpowershell.wordpress.com/2010/09/14/powershell-ews-managed-api-get-calendar-booked-time/

Comment: No I cannot see the "lunch hours" using Get (with FL too). YES I see Viva Insights created a LUNCH  repeating Appointment in the Calendar. Although if I delete that entry from Outlook, Viva Insights still shows the lunch Hour. So I need to find the original "Lunch hours" setting for "Viva Insights" and modify that.

Comment: Read following : https://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/104133  At bottom there is a link to troubleshooting